# noUiSlider value undefined after changing handle direction

Tags: javascript, slider, nouislider

I create a slider, change the `orientation:'vertical'`  and link the "span" with it so that I can update and set the values as I drag/tap the slider. It works well, but as soon as I put the Handle at the bottom with the `direction: 'rtl'`, span outputs `undefined`.

I saw the same problem on the [NoUiSlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-options/#section-direction) site although the slider is horizontal, but the problem is still there.

Per default, the `direction` of the handles of the slider is set to `"ltr"` or "left-to-right". When the orientation of the slider is set to `vertical` the Handle acts the same way, they adjust either "ltr = top-to-bottom" or "rtl = bottom-to-top".

```
var slider = document.getElementById('sl1');
noUiSlider.create(slider, {
    start: 1,
    step: 1,
    connect: 'lower',
    direction: 'rtl',
    orientation: 'vertical',
    range: {
        'min': 1,
        'max': 32
    },
    format: wNumb({
        decimals: 0,
    })
});

var input = document.getElementById('input-with-keypress1');

slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function(values, handle) {
    input.value = values[handle]; //When the slider value changes, update the   input
});

slider.noUiSlider.on('set', function(values, handle) {
            input.value = values[handle];
```

[JsFiddleDemo](http://jsfiddle.net/am33zjbf/28/)

I don't know why, but it seems the External Resource links won't render the slider, Excuse me but I'm a noob and maybe I just got the syntax wrong (works local though)..

Comment: The thing I noticed also is that, if you create two handles with the property `start: [0,0]`  the reading of values [works](http://tinypic.com/r/2yn54hw/8), the Image is from also from the [UiSlider site](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/)